# Can't get touch event with Qt and Angstrom

Tags: qt, events, touch, angstrom-linux, beagleboneblack

My goal is to make a QT application for Technexion DevKit TDM-3730 BlizzardPack. Everything is OK, but it is **impossible to click a button with a touchscreen**, while with mouse it's ok.

I've tried evtest, here its output:

```
root@devkit:/dev/input# evtest touchscreen0
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "prism_st"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (Sync)
  Event type 1 (Key)
    Event code 330 (Touch)
  Event type 3 (Absolute)
    Event code 0 (X)
      Value    115
      Min        0
      Max     1499
    Event code 1 (Y)
      Value    397
      Min        0
      Max      899
    Event code 24 (Pressure)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 10551.906098, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 735
Event: time 10551.906129, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 461
Event: time 10551.906129, type 3 (Absolute), code 24 (Pressure), value 255
Event: time 10551.906129, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.915772, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 734
Event: time 10551.915772, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 460
Event: time 10551.915802, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.925201, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 733
Event: time 10551.925201, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 459
Event: time 10551.925232, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.934570, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 732
Event: time 10551.934600, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.943999, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 730
Event: time 10551.944030, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 460
Event: time 10551.944030, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.951659, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 728
Event: time 10551.951690, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 462
Event: time 10551.951690, type 3 (Absolute), code 24 (Pressure), value 28
Event: time 10551.951690, -------------- Report Sync ------------
Event: time 10551.959014, type 3 (Absolute), code 0 (X), value 726
Event: time 10551.959044, type 3 (Absolute), code 1 (Y), value 464
Event: time 10551.959044, type 3 (Absolute), code 24 (Pressure), value 1
Event: time 10551.959044, -------------- Report Sync ------------
```

No matter how much I tapped there is no touch event (330).

I've made a GTK application and it's ok, but it isn't convenient at all. And it seems that touch-event processing realized inside GTK GUI. Am I right?

Here is my system parameters:

```
Host - Linux Mint 15, Linux version 3.8.0-19-generic, QT 5
Target - Angstrom, Linux version 2.6.37, qt4-embedded - 4.7.3-r33.1.9, tslib
Cpu - TI Sitara DM3730 @ 1Ghz
DSP Core - TMS320C64x+™ @ 800Mhz
```

TsLib environment variables are exported:

```
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/touchscreen0
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=Tslib:/dev/input/touchscreen0
```

I'm a beginner at QT (and at Embedded systems), so I'm followwing Derek Molloy tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kP7uvOu9hoQ on BeagleBone. But I have Technexion devkit. Beaglebone linux version is 3.2.34 and mine is 2.6.37.

Here is my test program main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTouchEvent>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

and here is mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->lineEdit->setText("DevKit");
}
```

And in Derek's tutorial it works ok. Could anyone tell me how I can enable qt source code to accept touch screen events?

Thank you in advance.

Egor

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find this video useful in setting up your QT environment and configuring QT embedded on the BBB.

[Beaglebone: Qt Creator for C++ ARM Embedded Linux Development ]

Comment: I understand, but I need it for my dev kit, otherwise I wouldn't ask such a question